# interactions terms in multiple imputations (Amelia or other mi packages)

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a question about interaction terms in multiple imputations. My understanding is that the imputation model is supposed to include all information that is used in the later analysis including any transformations or interactions of variables (the Amelia user guide also makes this statement). But when I include the interaction term `int=x1*x2` in the imputation, the imputed value for `int` is not equal to `x1*x2`. For example, when I have a binary variable `x2` and a continuous variable `x1`, `int` should be zero when `x2` is zero. That is not the case for the imputed values of `int`. So how do I treat interactions in multiple imputations? Below is some example code illustrating the question.

```
library("Amelia")

n = 100
p.na = 0.1
n.na = ceiling(n*p.na)
set.seed(12345)
# create data
df = data.frame(
    'x1' = rnorm(n),
    'x2' = rbinom(n,1,0.5),
    'int'= NA
)
df$x1[sample(1:100,n.na)]=NA
df$x1[sample(1:100,n.na)]=NA
df$int = with(df,x1*x2)
# impute
df.mi = amelia(df,m=2,noms=c("x2"))

# comparison
round(cbind(df,df.mi$imputations[[1]])[1:10,],2)
cbind(
    'df' = with(df,int==x1*x2),
    'df.mi' = with(df.mi$imputations[[1]],int==x1*x2))
```

And some of the output (row 6 is one of the cases discussed above for which `int!=x1*x2`)

```
      DF           DF (imputed)
      x1 x2   int    x1 x2   int
1   0.59  1  0.59  0.59  1  0.59
2   0.71  1  0.71  0.71  1  0.71
3  -0.11  0  0.00 -0.11  0  0.00
4  -0.45  1 -0.45 -0.45  1 -0.45
5   0.61  1  0.61  0.61  1  0.61
6     NA  1    NA  0.24  1  0.48
7   0.63  0  0.00  0.63  0  0.00
8  -0.28  0  0.00 -0.28  0  0.00
9  -0.28  1 -0.28 -0.28  1 -0.28
10 -0.92  1 -0.92 -0.92  1 -0.92
```

Answer (score 2):

I think , in any cases you give the information to Amelia that int is the result of a transformation , x1*x2. So it treats it as a simple variable.
But you can perform a Post-transformation in the imputed data like this:

```
   df.mi = transform(df.mi, int = x2*x1)
```

Comparing to the original data you get this result:

```
mm <- cbind(df,df.mi$imputations$imp1)
mm[mm$x2==0 & is.na(mm$int),]
   x1 x2 int         x1 x2 int
45 NA  0  NA  0.3144084  0   0
49 NA  0  NA -1.1741704  0   0
76 NA  0  NA -0.2018450  0   0
```

**EDIT** I think I get better result using `mice` package which :

> "The algorithm imputes an incomplete column (the target column) by
>   generating 'plausible' synthetic values given other columns in the
>   data."

Using your data , I compare the original data.frame to all the imputed data sets when x2 is equal to 0.

```
library(mice)
rr <- mice(df)
mm1 <- cbind(df,do.call(cbind,lapply(1:5,function(i)complete(rr , i))))
mm1[mm1$x2==0 & is.na(mm1$int),]

  x1 x2 int        x1 x2       int        x1 x2        int         x1 x2       int        x1 x2       int        x1 x2        int
20 NA  0  NA 0.5168547  0 -0.162311 0.6203798  0  0.0000000  0.8881394  0 0.0000000 0.9371405  0 0.8248701 0.5855288  0  0.0000000
23 NA  0  NA 0.5168547  0  0.000000 0.4911883  0  0.0000000 -1.8323773  0 0.0000000 0.5855288  0 0.0000000 0.5855288  0  0.0000000
31 NA  0  NA 0.5168547  0  0.000000 0.1495920  0 -0.3240866  2.3305120  0 1.6324456 1.1207127  0 0.8544517 0.5674033  0  0.0000000
60 NA  0  NA 0.5365237  0  0.000000 0.2542712  0  0.0000000  1.5934885  0 0.9371405 0.7094660  0 0.5168547 0.2542712  0 -0.3079534
```

Comment: Yes, I can do that. But when I create the interaction after the imputation, doesn't that omit the interaction term from the imputation procedure? The Amelia manual states "It is crucial to include at least as much information as will be used in the analysis model. That is, any variable that will be in the analysis model should also be in the imputation model. This includes any transformations or interactions of variables that will appear in the analysis model."(p. 10) Without the term, I impute the general pattern ignoring the difference of a relation between e.g. racial groups.

Comment: @user2503795 I see your point. I read also that from the documentation  but I can't find how you can give this extra information to Amelia. But, what I would do is (I am not a statistician)  to apply a model on data before including some Missings, and compare it to the same model applied to all imputed data.

Comment: @user2503795 I edit my answer to use another missings values package `mi`.

Comment: @user2503795 You are likely not still working on this, but my interpretation of the Amelia documentation is that you are supposed to include the interaction term in the imputation _and_ do the transformation afterward to make it consistent, but this method (JAV) has significant bias. It is likely better to omit the interaction term from the imputation entirely. There is an R package called scmfcs that extends MICE (not Amelia) to be significantly better at this. To learn more about this, look at the interaction terms section here: https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-knowledge.html