# Creating multiple interaction terms identified by vectors using "transform" in R

Tags: r, transform, apply

I am using Amelia to multiply impute missing data. Since interactions are going to be in my analysis, I need to include them when estimating missing values, and Amelia does not do that automatically for me. So I computed the 18 interaction terms and had Amelia generate multiply imputed data. However, the imputed interaction terms are not necessarily consistent with their constituent terms, which also had missing data that Amelia imputed. Therefore, [as suggested in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628481/interactions-terms-in-multiple-imputations-amelia-or-other-mi-packages), in order to run my analysis I need to compute new interaction terms based on the complete values and the imputed values. Amelia's developers suggest to do that via 'transform', which, if applied on the whole Amelia object, works across all the imputations.

So in essence my problem is this. I have a dataframe, df, and two vectors of variables:

```
a <- c("var1","var2","var3")
b <- c("varA","varB","varC","varD","varE","varF")
```

I could manually created 18 interaction terms using 'transform', as in:

```
df <- transform(df, var1.A = var1*varA)
df <- transform(df, var2.A = var2*varA)
df <- transform(df, var1.B = var1*varB)
df <- transform(df, var2.B = var1*varB)
```

And so on and so forth. However, I would rather use some command of the 'apply' family to do it all in one go and avoid errors.

Any suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear which functions get parsed by 'Amelia'.  An option would be to create an expression that will be parsed within a `for` loop and assign the output to initial object 'df'

```
#create combination of variables as a 2 column dataset
ab <- expand.grid(a, b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#create the column names of the new columns
nm1 <- sub("\\.var", ".", do.call(paste, c(ab, sep=".")))  

#create a pasted expression 
ab1 <- sprintf("transform(df, %s = %s*%s)", nm1, ab[,1], ab[,2]) 

#evaluate the expression within for loop and assign it back to 'df'
for(i in seq_along(ab1)) df <- eval(parse(text = ab1[i]))
```

-output

```
df
#  var1 var2 var3 varA varB varC varD varE varF var1.A var2.A var3.A var1.B var2.B var3.B var1.C var2.C var3.C var1.D var2.D var3.D var1.E var2.E
#1    3    9    6    9    1    7    3    2    5     27     81     54      3      9      6     21     63     42      9     27     18      6     18
#2    3    3    4    2    5    1    3    7    4      6      6      8     15     15     20      3      3      4      9      9     12     21     21
#3    7    7    7    1    7    6    4    6    3      7      7      7     49     49     49     42     42     42     28     28     28     42     42
#4    5    8    7    5    2    6    2    7    2     25     40     35     10     16     14     30     48     42     10     16     14     35     56
#5    6    3    3    2    3    1    9    9    1     12      6      6     18      9      9      6      3      3     54     27     27     54     27
#  var3.E var1.F var2.F var3.F
#1     12     15     45     30
#2     28     12     12     16
#3     42     21     21     21
#4     49     10     16     14
#5     27      6      3      3
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:9, 5 * 9, replace = TRUE), 
     5, 9, dimnames = list(NULL, c(a, b))))
```